# javascript object multi-dimensional to array one dimenstional

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion

I have variable **rawData** like this:

```
let rawData = [
  {
    title: '1',
    result: '1',
    child: [
      {
        title: '1-1',
        result: '1-1',
        child: [
          {
            title: '1-1-1',
            result: '1-1-1',
            child: [
              {
                title: '1-1-1-1',
                result: '1-1-1-1',
                child: [
                  {
                    title: '1-1-1-1-1',
                    result: '1-1-1-1-1',
                  },
                ],
              },
              {
                title: '1-1-1-2',
                result: '1-1-1-2',
              },
              {
                title: '1-1-1-3',
                result: '1-1-1-3',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

and with my function. it runs as expected, here's my function:

```
let normalizeArray = [];
function test(array) {
  for (const key in array) {
    if (array.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      const element = array[key];
      if (element.hasOwnProperty('child')) {
        test(element.child);
        delete element.child;
        normalizeArray.unshift(Object.assign({}, element));
      } else {
        normalizeArray.push(Object.assign({}, element));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and return (expected):

```
[
  { title: '1', result: '1' },
  { title: '1-1', result: '1-1' },
  { title: '1-1-1', result: '1-1-1' },
  { title: '1-1-1-1', result: '1-1-1-1' },
  { title: '1-1-1-1-1', result: '1-1-1-1-1' },
  { title: '1-1-1-2', result: '1-1-1-2' },
  { title: '1-1-1-3', result: '1-1-1-3' },
];
```

But, if the rawData like this:

```
let rawData = [
  {
    title: '1',
    result: '1',
    child: [
      {
        title: '1-1',
        result: '1-1',
        child: [
          {
            title: '1-1-1',
            result: '1-1-1',
            child: [
              {
                title: '1-1-1-1',
                result: '1-1-1-1',
                child: [
                  {
                    title: '1-1-1-1-1',
                    result: '1-1-1-1-1',
                  },
                ],
              },
              {
                title: '1-1-1-2',
                result: '1-1-1-2',
              },
              {
                title: '1-1-1-3',
                result: '1-1-1-3',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: '2',
    result: '2',
    child: [
      {
        title: '2-2',
        result: '2-2',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: '3',
    result: '3',
  },
];
```

with my function, it return :

```
[
  { title: '2', result: '2' },
  { title: '1', result: '1' },
  { title: '1-1', result: '1-1' },
  { title: '1-1-1', result: '1-1-1' },
  { title: '1-1-1-1', result: '1-1-1-1' },
  { title: '1-1-1-1-1', result: '1-1-1-1-1' },
  { title: '1-1-1-2', result: '1-1-1-2' },
  { title: '1-1-1-3', result: '1-1-1-3' },
  { title: '2-2', result: '2-2' },
  { title: '3', result: '3' },
];
```

How I could got a result like this:

```
[
  { title: '1', result: '1' },
  { title: '1-1', result: '1-1' },
  { title: '1-1-1', result: '1-1-1' },
  { title: '1-1-1-1', result: '1-1-1-1' },
  { title: '1-1-1-1-1', result: '1-1-1-1-1' },
  { title: '1-1-1-2', result: '1-1-1-2' },
  { title: '1-1-1-3', result: '1-1-1-3' },
  { title: '2', result: '2' },
  { title: '2-2', result: '2-2' },
  { title: '3', result: '3' },
];
```

And if you could help me to produce leaner code, feel free to help me. I'm still new in javascript

Comment: How about just using a suitable `sort()` afterwards? Might also simplify your other function a little bit.

Comment: hmm? the dummy data actually was string: like title: 'alice in wonderland', result: 'good', that number just to make it more clear... or i miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could get clean looking with spread operator and recursion

```
function flatten(dataArray) {
  const result = [];
   dataArray.map(d => {
    const { child, ...rest } = d;
    result.push(rest);
    if(child && child.length) result.push(...flatten(child));
  });
   return result;
}
console.log(flatten(rawData));
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting/shifting/unshifting, you can extract the properties from the array item immediately with destructuring. Push the `title` and `result` to the result array as an object, then do a recursive call if `child` exists. This way, the result array will be the output of an ordinary depth-first strategy:

```
function doFlat(inputArr, resultsArr = []) {
  for (const { child, title, result } of inputArr) {
    resultsArr.push({ title, result });
    if (child) {
      doFlat(child, resultsArr);
    }
  }
  return resultsArr;
}
```

By putting the results array as a default parameter which gets passed along to every recursive call, you only ever create *one* array, which is more efficient than creating a new array for every function call and then iterating over it in its caller.

```js
function doFlat(inputArr, resultsArr = []) {
  for (const { child, title, result } of inputArr) {
    resultsArr.push({ title, result });
    if (child) {
      doFlat(child, resultsArr);
    }
  }
  return resultsArr;
}

let rawData = [
  {
    title: '1',
    result: '1',
    child: [
      {
        title: '1-1',
        result: '1-1',
        child: [
          {
            title: '1-1-1',
            result: '1-1-1',
            child: [
              {
                title: '1-1-1-1',
                result: '1-1-1-1',
                child: [
                  {
                    title: '1-1-1-1-1',
                    result: '1-1-1-1-1',
                  },
                ],
              },
              {
                title: '1-1-1-2',
                result: '1-1-1-2',
              },
              {
                title: '1-1-1-3',
                result: '1-1-1-3',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: '2',
    result: '2',
    child: [
      {
        title: '2-2',
        result: '2-2',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: '3-3',
    result: '3-3',
  },
];

console.log(doFlat(rawData));
```